# CSS-Grid: Make last row of unknown number of rows take the remaining height

Tags: css, css-grid

I know how to make the last row of a grid fill the remaining vertical space using `minmax(0, 1fr)`.

What I need to know, how do I solve this for a dynamic number of rows?

This example explicitly defines 3 rows:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(auto, 30px)) minmax(0, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 2px dashed #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to define `grid-template-rows` such as that I don't have to know how many rows the `div.grid-container` has?

Comment: @Paulie_D Seems neither related nor a duplicate to me. I'm looking for a variable `grid-template-rows`-definition that allows to solve the problem I presented.

Comment: Eh, OK but  since you can't define the last row it would be in the implicit grid and I don't think you can target that yet (`grid-row:-1` doesn't work yet) AFAIK.

Comment: ahhh...that's more like the dupe I was looking for! ☺

Comment: So that means it currently cannot be achieved. That's too bad, since I'm certain this would be frequent scenario for CSS grid. :(

Comment: I was hoping for something the likes of `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto) minmax(0, 1fr);`.

Comment: it really is a typical flex job, it is a 1 column layout, no need of a grid used to draw columns & rows that children can be spanning through ;) . Aside, for a repeating pattern , you should look at grid-auto-rows .  (flex create a grid and children go inside the grid cell defined  , flex draws  columns or   rows and children lay themselves independantly from the others row or column.) it is very different

Comment: a hacky idea: https://jsfiddle.net/n5gro14u/